# quantity separation in different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

Help me for quantity separation formula with max volume per line item this is base on total

if the item is dairy with 150 pcs per box and the quantity is 1000pcs the result will be box1(150),box2(150),box3(150),box4(150),box5(150),box6(150),box7(100)

if the item is meat with 20 pcs per box and the quantity is 184pcs the result will be box1(20),box2(20),box3(20),box4(20),box5(20),box6(20),box7(20),box8(20),box9(20),box10(4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following if using `MS365`:

[image]

---

```
=LET(α,C2/B2,δ,MOD(α,1),DROP(HSTACK(SEQUENCE(,α,,0),δ)*B2,,-(δ=0)))
```

---

For Older Versions:

```
=IFNA(IFS(COLUMN(A$1)<=$C2/$B2,$B2,COLUMN(A$1)=CEILING($C2/$B2,1),MOD($C2,$B2)),"")
```

---

Comment: Thanks the let formula help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want results in separate cells you may use a formula:

```
=LET(n,SEQUENCE(1,ROUNDUP(A2/B2,)),"box"&n&"("&IF(A2>n*B2,B2,A2+B2-n*B2)&")")
```

If results should be in one cell, separated with commas, you can combine them using `TEXTJOIN` function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,LET(n,SEQUENCE(1,ROUNDUP(A5/B5,)),"box"&n&"("&IF(A5>n*B5,B5,A5+B5-n*B5)&")"))
```

[image: Fill Boxes]